# Did humans ever return to their former population in The Matrix World?

Tags: the-matrix

During the Machine War, humans nearly went extinct. The last known human city was Zion. Did free humans ever return to life before the Machine War, or did they barely live life, being grown in fields, and trying to sustain their free but dwindling population?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**We don't see far enough forward, in the world of the Matrix, to determine the shape of future human society.**

The farthest we go within the Matrix 'verse is a few years after Neo's death in the third film. The events of [The Matrix Online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_Online) outline a world where Zionese free humans are fighting against a range of other clans and enemies for control of the surface and broadly in opposition to the (overwhelmingly powerful) machine forces in an event referred to as the [Second Machine War](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Machine_War). Most humans remain inside the Power Plants. The population of free humans (red pills) is roughly double that of the events of *Revolutions*.

Comment: Although we may find out in the upcoming *Matrix 4*.

Comment: @Mithical - It'll be interesting to see if they chuck the entire Matrix Online plot into the bin. My gut instinct is that they will